# Is it decidable whether the language of a given CFG contains a palindrome?

Tags: computability, context-free, undecidability

> Given a context-free grammar G. Is it decidable, if the language $L(G)$, which is generated by G, contains a palindrome?

My suggestion is, that it is undecidable, but I do not have an idea for a formal prove. Any hints?

Comment: It can be proved undecidable using the fact that we cannot decide whether two CF languages have a nonempty intersection. Or, whether the Post Correspondence Problem has a solution; the latter will lead to undecidability even for the subfamily of linear languages:  [Palindromes and linear grammars](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/palindromes-and-linear-grammars)